# Static Analysis Failed. Error Details: PMD Command Failed! Enable "Show StdErr" setting for more info

Tags: vscode-extensions, static-analysis, pmd

I have installed APEX PMD extension in vscode. I have added C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin\java to Sys env Path variable. I have downloaded pmd-bin-7.0.0-rc3 and added  C:\pmd-bin-7.0.0-rc3\bin to the Sys env Path variable. I have selected to run the static analyzer to Run On file Save.

The error i am getting on File Save is as below
Static Analysis Failed. Error Details: PMD Command Failed! Enable "Show StdErr" setting for more info.

I tried using a different version of PMD as such as pmd-bin-6.55.0, i am still getting the same error. any suggestion of how to resolve this.

please note i am able to run the PMD successfully via command line. I want to use this on VSCode

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue and I am trying to find the root cause.

I suspect it can be an issue with the Java version/ Java configuration that is set up in the system. For me, it is showing as such:

[image: Apex PMD - Output Console Error]

You can enable the "Show StdErr" in the PMD Setting (as mentioned in the error), go to the output console, and select "Apex PMD" on the right. You will be able to see the PMD error in the output console:

[image: Setting up StdErr for Apex PMD in Output console]

You can check out this [Githug Issue](https://github.com/ChuckJonas/vscode-apex-pmd/issues/34) for more info.
Let me know once you fix this issue.